# Bootstrap empty col as spacing in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/fd7x6osk/

I'm using two empty div's either side of the centeral block as spaces

This seems to work in modern browser but I'm worried about IE8.

I haven't been able to test but I imagine the div's will collapse because they have no content.

Does anyone know if they will collapse in IE8 and if it does how could I fix it.

Would adding non breaking spaces be an option.

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-1 block"></div>

            <div class="col-sm-10 block center"></div>

            <div class="col-sm-1 block"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `offset` instead of `block`.

Here's my solution.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-smoffset-1"></div>
</div>
```

Try this, and I think it will work fine on IE8.